# Ruby rails quarterly loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a banking application whereby a statement table is displayed. At present with the code below the table has a column for year and beside that a column for each month and beside that a column for each bank account. I wish to change it so that it displays four quarters for each year. How would i go about doing this?

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th.year(rowspan=2) Year
      %th.accounts{colspan: @customer.accounts.size} Accounts
    %tr
      - fetch_cu_accounts(@customer.id).each do |account|
        %th= account.name
  - @today.year.downto(@today.year - 3) do |year|
    %tbody
      - x = (@today.year == year) ? @today.month : 12
      - x.downto(1) do |month|
        %tr
          - if month == x
            %td{rowspan: x}= year
          %td
          - fetch_cu_accounts(@customer.id).each do |account|
            %td
              - stmt = account.statement(year, month)
              = link_to 'View', url(:statements, :show, id: stmt.to_s)
              = link_to image_tag('/icons/document-pdf.png', alt: 'Download PDF'), url(:statements, :show, id: stmt, format: :pdf), class: :pdf
```

Comment: Quarters instead of months?

Comment: @David Aldridge Yeah please!

Comment: quarter = ((@today.month - 1) / 3) + 1

Comment: Which particular bit are you having trouble with? Working out what the current quarter is, generating a list of quarters ... ?